# SharePoint WebServices via Javascript - List Views

Tags: sharepoint, service, view, web

I'm trying to get a list of all the lists, views and their associated guids via a javascript call. I have successfully been able to get the list guids using the GetListCollection method in the List service. However, this service does not return the view guids which i also need. Is there another web service that can give me this information?

**Update:**
Okay, I figured it out.  There is a corresponding web service for views (views.asmx - GetViewCollection). I just need to query this service while iterating through the List items.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You could use the _vti_bin/lists.asmx service, once you have the lists names, do something like this:

```
node.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_ID"].Value;
```

This would return the list Guid.

Once You have the Id, You'll need to do this:

```
Change “%7B” to “{”, all “%2D” to “-“ and all “%7D” to “}”
```

Comment: I already have the list guid, i need all of the associated view guids.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Can You use Object Model? If so, then try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getview.aspx (Btw, how do You add the comment here? I'm new at StackOverflow...